# "non-virtual thunk to ...." error in iOs

Tags: iphone, gcc, linker, thunk

In my iPhone app i am getting the following error:

```
"non-virtual thunk to metaio::UnifeyeMobileiPhone::UnifeyeMobileiPhone()"
```

and the point where the error occured is:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    // Tear down context.
    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == context)
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];

    // delete unifeye instance
    if( unifeyeMobile )
    {
        delete unifeyeMobile; //here got the error
        unifeyeMobile = NULL;
    }

    [context release];

    [glView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I googled for a solution for this issue, and I got something in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544152/mac-gcc-non-virtual-thunk-error). And there it says that this error is a "compiler bug". I have changed the Debug mode to Release and tested, but still having the issue. Any idea? And I am having this issue only on iPhone 4S. On iPhone 3GS it is working fine.

Comment: does this also happen in the example application that is included in the SDK? have you tried switching compilers? (e.g. instead of llvm-gcc, clang - which is also provided by the iOS SDK)